# Scrollview paging within a tableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to create a scrollview with paging enabled,with 5 pages,but the problem is these page must hold tableview.how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    scroll.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*5, 460);
    CGFloat x=0;
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+10, 10, 300, 440) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        table.delegate=self;
        table.dataSource=self;
        [scroll addSubview:table];
        [table release];
        x+=320;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    [scroll release];
```

Comment: you can put this code in rootViewController loadView or viewDidLoad method.

Comment: class rootview contoller does not implemnt the uitableview deligate protocol,,,i got this error

Comment: Sorry for the late, You need to declare scroll by `UIScrollView *scroll;` and you have to declare the table view delegate in _.h_ file `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`